# A Sequence Riddle

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

Here is a list of numerical sequences:

- 1, 3, 5, 4
- 2, 3, 5, 4
- 3, 5, 4
- 4
- 5, 4
- 6, 3, 5, 4
- ...and so on.

(1 is 3 and 2 is 3, but 1 is not 2 and 2 is not 1. The same rule applies to every number in the sequence.)

There is a simple rule that governs these sequences. What is it? 
Use spoiler tags in your answer, please.

Answer (score 6):

The rule is...

> The next number in the sequence is the number of characters in the previous number when spelled out.
> Each of the sequences end on 4 because it has 4 characters and the sequence is then essentially eternal.

Let's take a look at the first sequence:

> 1: 'o' + 'n' + 'e' = 3
> 3: 't' + 'h' + 'r' + 'e' + 'e' = 5
> 5: 'f' + 'i' + 'v' + 'e' = 4
> And 4 goes on forever so it is terminal.